# EasyMock to test SecurityException

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock, securityexception

I am trying to use easyMock to write a test, that tests SecurityException in the following code.

eg. for NumberFormatException I use the below.

> EasyMock.expect(mockEntityManager.find(UserProfile.class,"abc")).andThrow(new
>   NumberFormatException());

Any ideas on what to expect to throw SecurityException?

> public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent
>   uiComponent, String s) {
>
> EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager)Component.getInstance("entityManager");
>
> ```
>   if (s == null || s.equals("null")) {
>         return null;      } else {
>         try {
>             long i = Long.parseLong(s);
>             return entityManager.find(UserProfile.class, i);
>         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>             logger.error(e);
>         } catch (SecurityException e) {
>             logger.error(e);
>         }         }
>
>     return null;  }
> ```

Comment: Not sure I understand. What doesn't work if you just replace new NumberFormatException() by new SecurityException()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses..here is what I did to expect SecurityException.

```
MyClass abc = new MyClass();

EasyMock.expect(mockEntityManager.find(MyClass.class,111L)).andThrow(new SecurityException());

EasyMock.replay(mockEntityManager);

Object target = abc.getAsObject(mockFacesContext, mockUiComponent,"111");

Assert.assertEquals(null, target);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that you haven't written that code, and that's why you're wondering what might throw `SecurityException`. The answer is *nothing*, as long as you're using a good implementation of EntityManager.

The documented version of EntityManager.find()[enter link description here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) doesn't throw `SecurityException`. **BUT** if you're running that code inside a J2EE app server that uses a custom version of EntityManager, it could be that it throws that exception... But I don't think it should.